# Looping through a folder with Excel files scraping date from selected cells using VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I would like to loop through Excel files in a specific folder. After opening a single file, the macro goes to a specified tab to copy data from four cells (say A2; B3; C5 and D6 which I have named Region, DateSales, Sales and Salesman) to a master file.

I found VBA code.

```vb
Sub getDataFromWbs()

    Dim wb As Workbook, ws As Worksheet
    Dim Region As String
    Dim DateSales As Date
    Dim Sales As Integer
    Dim Salesman As String

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

    'Path to the folder
    Set fldr = fso.GetFolder("C:\Users\xxxxx\yyyyyy\Desktop\Sales\")

    'Next available row in Master Workbook
    y = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row + 1

    'Loop through each file in that folder
    For Each wbFile In fldr.files

        'Make sure looping only through files ending in .xlsx (Excel files)
        If fso.GetExtensionName(wbFile.Name) = "xlsx" Then

            'Open current book
            Set wb = Workbooks.Open(wbFile.Path)

            Region = Sheets(1).Cells(1, 2).Value
            DateSales = Sheets(1).Cells(2, 3).Value
            Sales = Sheets(1).Cells(3, 5).Value
            Salesman = Sheets(1).Cells(4, 6).Value

            'Loop through each sheet (ws)
            For Each ws In wb.Sheets

                'Last row in that sheet (ws)
                wsLR = ws.Cells(rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

                'Loop through each record (row 2 through last row)
                For x = 2 To wsLR
                
                'Put column 1,2,3 and 4 of current sheet (ws) into row y of master sheet, then increase row y to next row
                    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(y, 1) = ws.Cells(x, 1).Value = Region 'col 1
                    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(y, 2) = ws.Cells(x, 2).Value = DateSales
                    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(y, 3) = ws.Cells(x, 3).Value = Sales
                    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(y, 4) = ws.Cells(x, 4).Value = Salesman

                    y = y + 1
                Next x

            Next ws

            'Close current book
            wb.Close

        End If

    Next wbFile

End Sub
```

The end results are FALSE and TRUE values in the master file.

Comment: What exactly is the problem with the code?

Comment: It does not copy correctly the data from files in the folder and the end resuls I get are FALSE and TRUE values in the master folder.

Comment: I suggest you add that to your question rather than expecting people to search comments.

Comment: `ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(y, 1) = ws.Cells(x, 1).Value = Region` will produce TRUE or FALSE.

Comment: Ok, I will do as you suggeted in my next inquiry. Can you help me and write how should I change the code to get the proper data from the copied cells?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Import Cell Values From Closed Workbooks (FSO)

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub ImportData()

    Dim fso As Object: Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

    Dim fsoFolder As Object
    Set fsoFolder = fso.GetFolder("C:\Users\xxxxx\yyyyyy\Desktop\Sales\")

    Dim dwb As Workbook: Set dwb = ThisWorkbook ' workbook containing this code
    Dim dws As Worksheet: Set dws = dwb.Sheets("Sheet1")
    Dim dRow As Long: dRow = dws.Cells(dws.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row ' last

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Dim swb As Workbook, sws As Worksheet, fsoFile As Object, sPath As String

    For Each fsoFile In fsoFolder.Files
        
        sPath = fsoFile.Path
        
        If StrComp(fso.GetExtensionName(sPath), "xlsx", vbTextCompare) = 0 Then
            
            Set swb = Workbooks.Open(sPath)
            Set sws = swb.Worksheets(1)
            
            dRow = dRow + 1 ' next
            
            dws.Cells(dRow, "A").Value = sws.Range("A2").Value
            dws.Cells(dRow, "B").Value = sws.Range("B3").Value
            dws.Cells(dRow, "C").Value = sws.Range("C5").Value
            dws.Cells(dRow, "D").Value = sws.Range("D6").Value
            
            swb.Close SaveChanges:=False ' only read from
        
        End If
    
    Next fsoFile

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

    MsgBox "Data imported.", vbInformation

End Sub
```

Comment: VBasic2008, this is what I have been loking for. Thank you very much for fixing my problem. Again, thanks a lot!!!

Comment: VBasic2008, I need another piece of help if this is possible. The file extension of the Excel files I need the data from chenged to xlsm (the files include macros). So while loading the dat a I have to manually click Enable Macros button for each open file and this is very annoying. How to modify the above Sub routine to enable the macros in the opened files (not to press the Enable Macros button using mouse clik)?

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments, you write the result of comparison to the cells value. Which will be TRUE or FALSE, thats what you see as a result. To copy the actual data, try to change these four lines of code:

```
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Cells(y, 1) = ws.Cells(x, 1).Value ' Region
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Cells(y, 2) = ws.Cells(x, 2).Value ' DateSales
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Cells(y, 3) = ws.Cells(x, 3).Value ' Sales
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Cells(y, 4) = ws.Cells(x, 4).Value ' Salesman
```